# Why does a compiler allow a user to change the type of an 'auto' variable?

Tags: c++, g++, auto

I expected the `auto` keyword to deduce the type of a variable from an intializer once and keep that type throughout the code. To my surprise, my compiler (`g++ 9.3.0`) allows me to change it's type and it still works. This is sort of acceptable to me when I first use the variable as an int and then as a float. But when I use the `auto` keyword to declare a string and then assign a float value to that variable, the compiler doesn't throw an error but also doesn't print the value after the float assignment. Can someone explain why it allows assigning a float value to a string variable in the first place? Does the compiler just accept the new assignment each time? Or does it throw some kind of exception that I am not able to catch? Code below -

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 auto x = '2';
 
 std::cout << x << std::endl;
 
 x = 3.0; // Why is this allowed?
 
 std::cout << x << std::endl; // This won't print
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will do a narrowing conversion from double to char (it will not change the type of x).  The second line will print a 3 character (not a '3') and this is an invisible character but it does work it will print the newline. auto may seem like a 'magic' thing but it is actually very well defined.

Comment: Now try `x = 65.0`

Comment: "But when I use the auto keyword to declare a string" - no, it's not a string. It is a `char` - a single character.

Comment: The trouble with c/c++ compilers is that they think we know what we're doing ;) -- morale: always enable all warnings.

Comment: Another page in the "implicit conversions were a mistake" book.

Comment: `auto` has nothing to do with what you're seeing. Try `char x = '2';`, which defines `x` the same way that `auto` would, and you'll see the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show you what's going on I extended the example with some compile time type checks:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto x = '2';

    // decltype(x) is the type for variable x
    // compare it at compile time with char type
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), char>);

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    x = 3.0; // Why is this allowed? because it does a narrowing conversion from double to char
    // my compiler even gives this warning :
    // main.cpp(11,6): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'char', possible loss of data
    
    // type of x is still the same and it is still a char
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), char>);

    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl; // the cast is here to be able to print the actual value of the char

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you! What compiler are you using, btw? I tried the same code with g++ 9.3.0 using -Wall switch but that didn't show me any warnings.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm using mscv. And indeed even adding -Wconversion to gcc (https://godbolt.org/z/qrxnchhar) doesn't trigger this warning for gcc (weird).

Answer (score 3):

> But when I use the auto keyword to declare a string

You are confused. This code declares a variable of type `char`:

```
auto x = '2';
```

If you do want to declare a string you have to use double quotes:

```
auto x = "2";
```

The subsequent assignment of `3.0` will not compile with this change.